# BASH command: How to save output of bash command into variable and later pipeline into command

Tags: bash

i have a question about how to store the output into variable and then later pipeline into another command

```
var=$(ps -auxc | grep -vE '^USER'  )

#get top CPU 
echo $var |  sort -nr -k3 | head -1  
#get top memory
echo $var | sort -nr -k4 | head -1
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would always work:

```
IFS= read -rd '' var < <(ps -auxc | grep -vE '^USER')  ## -d '' may be -d $'\0'
echo -n "$var" | sort -nr -k3 | head -1
```

However using `readarray` could:

```
readarray -t var < <(ps -auxc | grep -vE '^USER')
printf '%s\n' "${var[@]}" | sort -nr -k4 | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use quotes in assignment and while accessing variable:

```
var="$(ps -auxc | grep -vE '^USER')"

#get top CPU 
sort -nr -k3 <<< "$var" | head -1  
#get top memory
sort -nr -k4 <<< "$var" | head -1
```

Comment: I don't think using `""` on assignments would give a difference. For the answer however, it's quite enough if the user is not too sensitive about the last newline as `$()` always chops it out.

Comment: @konsolebox: Yes that's right, while assigning `""` may not be necessary.

Comment: @user3821571: Consider accepting any of the answers your liked here.